# Map tilt down and rotation in GMap.Net WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, gmap.net

I am looking forward to implementing Driving Navigation in GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation. Would it be possible to tilt down and rotate the map.

I think the bearing does the rotation, but I am not sure how to tilt up or tilt down.

`mapControl.Bearing = 10;`
`mapControl.Bearing -= 10;`

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. GMap.NET is focused on showing 2D maps, not 3D ones. In consequence it's only possible to change the bearing (as you already mentioned) but not the camera tilt.

```
 public static void gmapControlLoadEvent(GMapControl gMapControl)
        {
            gMapControl.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleHybridMap;

            GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = AccessMode.ServerAndCache;

            gMapControl.MinZoom = 4;
            gMapControl.MaxZoom = 20;
            gMapControl.MouseWheelZoomType = GMap.NET.MouseWheelZoomType.MousePositionWithoutCenter;
            gMapControl.CanDragMap = true;
            gMapControl.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left;
            gMapControl.IgnoreMarkerOnMouseWheel = true;

            //gMapControl.ShowCenter = false; //HIDE THE UGLY CROSS

            goToCoordinates(gMapControl, Variables.latitud, Variables.longitud);
            applyDefaultZoom(gMapControl);
        }

        public static void applyDefaultZoom(GMapControl gMapControl)
        {
            try
            {
                double desiredHeightMeters = Convert.ToDouble(0.01);
                int zoomLevel = calculateZoomLevel(gMapControl, desiredHeightMeters);
                gMapControl.Zoom = zoomLevel;
            }
            catch
            {
                gMapControl.Zoom = 0.5;
            }
        }

        public static int calculateZoomLevel(GMapControl gMapControl, double desiredHeightInMeters)
        {
            double tileSizeMeters = 256;

            double latitude = gMapControl.Position.Lat * Math.PI / 180;
            double circumference = 2 * Math.PI * Variables.EARTH_RADIUS_METERS * Math.Cos(latitude);

            double zoomLevel = Math.Log((circumference * gMapControl.Zoom) / (desiredHeightInMeters * tileSizeMeters));

            return (int)Math.Round(zoomLevel);
        }

        public static void updatePositionOnGmap(GMapControl gMapControl)
        {
            //gMapControl.Bearing = Variables.heading; //THE USELESS BEARING

            Tuple<double, double> nuevasCoordenadas = UtilidadesCoordenadas.calculateNewPosition(
                    Variables.latitud,
                    Variables.longitud,
                    Variables.kph,
                    Variables.heading);

            goToCoordinates(gMapControl, nuevasCoordenadas.Item1, nuevasCoordenadas.Item2);

            Variables.latitud = nuevasCoordenadas.Item1;
            Variables.longitud = nuevasCoordenadas.Item2;

            gMapControl.Bearing = Variables.norteMapa;
        }

        public static void goToCoordinates(GMapControl gMapControl, Double latitude, Double longitude)
        {
            gMapControl.Position = new PointLatLng(latitude, longitude);
            applyDefaultZoom(gMapControl);
            gMapControl.Refresh();
        }
```

This bearing change was useless on my case, because the map labels appear flipped, i.e. still attached to the original bearing (at least with Google maps).

Partial solution for your problem:

I ditched Gmap.NET and tried a Google API paid approach, adding the webView2 nuget package.

Sadly never found a way to interact with it from Windows Forms, for real time scrolling a pure javascript solution may be needed.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    webView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
    webView2.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += WebView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
}

private void WebView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsSuccess)

    {
        
        string googleMapsHtml = @"
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                    <head>
                        <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' />
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <iframe
                            width='600'
                            height='450'
                            style='border:0'
                            loading='lazy'
                            allowfullscreen
                            referrerpolicy='no-referrer-when-downgrade'
                            src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=<YOUR_API_KEY>&q=19.419743726181796, -99.08883095309436'>
                        </iframe>
                    </body>
                    </html>
                ";

        webView2.CoreWebView2.NavigateToString(googleMapsHtml);
    }
    else
    {            
        MessageBox.Show("WebView2 initialization failed.");
    }
}
```

If you find a better solution, please let me know

TL:DR

https://developers.google.com/codelabs/maps-platform/webgl#0